What is the difference between Ardex K22 F and Liquid Backboard?
I noticed that Ardex has a few different self-levelers. For example, K22 F and Liquid Backerboard.  They both seem to serve the same purpose - self-leveling below flooring without the need for metal lath since they are reinforced.  As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the K22 F is twice as strong (but cheaper at most places).  Does anyone know why Ardex produces both of these products?  Is there a distinction between the two that I'm missing?  Does anyone have experience with both that they can share?
